# Why big projects are not splitting code to subdir in src

Tags: erlang

[riak_cs on github](https://github.com/basho/riak_cs/tree/develop/src)

If we look on listing files in src, it looks not pretty good. Why they don't split like

```
myproject
    include
    deps
    ebin
    rebar.config
    app.config
    src
        webmachine
            riak_cs_wm_bucker.erl
            riak_cs_wm_bucket_acl.erl
        storage
            riak_cs_storage.erl
            riak_cs_storage_console.erl
            riak_cs_storage_d.erl
...
```

Are there any reasons not store file in project like this? Or maybe create apps?

Comment: You really have to ask them.

Comment: Yes, and I can send pool request and wait for comments. But all repo in github are organized like this.

Comment: The OTP directory structure for applications does not have sub-directories in `src`. Even `deps` is not part of the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason src is not split is because the OTP directory structure forbids it, like @rvirding says,

http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#id73976

Also, there is little point in splitting the code base if all the modules belong to the same application.